# Get the minimum and maximum value of a Numpy MaskedArray raises AttributeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a masked array containing some real values and some duds. Via ipython, this is what I have set up:

```
In [31]: x                                                                      
Out[31]:                                                                        
masked_array(data=[--, --, --, 2.718281828459045, 3.141592653589793],           
             mask=[ True,  True,  True, False, False],                          
       fill_value='?',                                                          
            dtype=object)
```

Note: the reason `dtype=object` is because this is an actual [ring_buffer](https://gist.github.com/mtambos/aa435461084b5c0025d1) containing datetimes and float values. *However, for this it should not matter.*

I want to find the maximum and minimum of that array. [The documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html?highlight=maskedarray#minimum-maximum) points to the `.min(…)` and `.max(…)` methods to do just that. However, when I call them, I get this exception:

```
In [32]: x.max()                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------     
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)     
<ipython-input-32-031604a175b1> in <module>()                                   
----> 1 x.max()                                                                 

/home/usr/repos/proj/.tox/develop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.pyc in max(self, axis, out, fill_value, keepdims) 
   5707         if out is None:                                                 
   5708             result = self.filled(fill_value).max(                       
-> 5709                 axis=axis, out=out, **kwargs).view(type(self))          
   5710             if result.ndim:                                             
   5711                 # Set the mask                                          

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'view'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ma.max` fills the array with the `fill_value`, and then attempts a regular `max`.  So the fill and all elements have to have to comparable (>=).  But this `view` error is caused by the `object` dtype (even with a nice fill_value).  The reason is subtile, but it is evident that `np.ma` has not been thoroughly tested for the `object` dtype case.

Answer (score 2):

So the fact you're using `dtype=object` does matter. The masked array doesn't know how to properly handle these so just uses the standard `numpy.array` methods. The default fill value for `dtype=object` is `'?'`, hence the error you get.

You should **not** be mixing datatypes in a numpy array. It defeats every advantage you get from them. Use lists (or pandas if dealing with different columns of different types) instead. `max` will fail on a numpy array of floats and datetimes anyway.

```
x = array([datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 28, 8, 52, 2, 107691), 3.14, 2.78],
           dtype=object)

x.max()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-031604a175b1> in <module>()
----> 1 x.max()

C:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _amax(a, axis, out, keepdims)
     24 # small reductions
     25 def _amax(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
---> 26     return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
     27 
     28 def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False):

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'float'
```

Comment: I really do not like your answer because it means that lots of "clever" things I have done are now pointless. However, it does explain why my "clever" code is not half as clever as I thought it was… ☹

Comment: As for finding the maximum, whats wrong wither `max(obj for obj in x if isinstance(obj, float)` or whatever? Since numpy gives us no advantages, use python.

Comment: Well, I kinda want the advantages of numpy/pandas here. This is to get data from hardware sensors (so time and value) for only some time (thus ring buffer) and plot them using matplotlib (thus need for min./max to scale plot). I *could use* lists but $client will want more analysis on the data and thus numpy/pandas…